# Conditional inner joins based on row values MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a MSSQL table that is used for messages. I have clients, workers, and users, each with their own respective tables. For this messaging component, the message can be sent to a client worker or user. To differentiate between which type the the sender/receiver is, I have a column in the message table that is a tiny-int, 1 for users, 2 for clients, 3 for workers.

So, when i am attempting to receive the messages, what is the ideal way to retrieve the name of the sender from the corresponding table(clients, users, or workers) without doing multiple queries.

I know I can first do a query to check the type column, then do another query to get the name but I would rather not do this for performance issues.

Comment: Please add the table structures (primary + Foreign keys) with their relationships. Some example data might help too.

Comment: How many rows do you have in all 4 tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a generic view which simply lists the relevant columns from each plus the message type and then join to that from your messages table.

```
CREATE VIEW ExampleView
AS
begin
    SELECT 
        firstname,
        lastname,
        1 AS MessageType
    FROM 
    dbo.Users
    union ALL
    SELECT 
        firstname,
        lastname,
        2 AS MessageType
    FROM 
    dbo.Clients
    union ALL
    SELECT 
        firstname,
        lastname,
        3 AS MessageType
    FROM 
    dbo.Workers
END
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
     a.MessageText,
     isnull(b.Firstname,'')+ISNULL(b.lastname,'') AS Name
FROM Messaging a
INNER JOIN ExampleView b ON a.MessageType = b.MessageType
```

If space isn't a massive issue you could store the message type directly on the Users,Clients and Workers table and just join to that column... Better performance but not really as nice database design.

Comment: You missed a supplementary JOIN condition on entity's ID.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather large guess at your table structure based on your description. The performance will be down to indexes you have.

```
Select m.*,
       COALESCE(c.ClientName, w.WorkerName, u.UserName) as Name
FROM Messages m
LEFT JOIN Clients c on c.ClientId = m.UserId AND m.type = 2
LEFT JOIN Workers w on w.WorkerId = m.UserId AND m.type = 3
LEFT JOIN Users u on u.UserId = m.UserId AND m.type = 1
Where (c.ClientId is not null 
       OR
       w.WorkerId is not null
       OR
       u.UserId is not null)
```

Comment: As an alternative to CASE you could use COALESCE to get the appropriate name, if any.